# sencha touch admob, how to get live adds?

Tags: sencha-touch, admob

I can display a test ad using admob and sencha touch. But when test:false, ads are not displaying. I need to display ads from admob store.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe waiting for a day will work for you.